# kqueue on iphone?

Tags: ios, sockets, kqueue

I am porting a linux server to ios. It is a single threaded, event driven design
that uses kqueue on OSX to handle sockets and other events.  Is there something
similar on ios?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CoreFoundation. `CFRunLoop` can run an event loop for you, with sources including file descriptors and sockets.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. The original code uses kqueue, so I don't want to change this unless I have to.

Comment: Well, you're in luck. I assumed from the existence of the question that kqueue doesn't exist on iOS, but after looking at the headers, it does indeed seem to be there.

Comment: Old question, kqueue is available in iOS. Check Apple's example code: DirectoryWatcher.